# Laravel Query Builder Sub Query not returning specific inside loop

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to aggregate the following totals into a new collection to use a report, the Sub Query for total_outbound is not returning the correct count for the specific campaign_job_id

```
  $campaign_jobs_summary = new Collection();
    foreach ($campaign_jobs as $campaign_job) {
        $campaign_job_totals = DB::table("campaign_jobs")
            ->select('campaign_jobs.deploy_date', 'campaign_jobs.campaign_id', 'campaign_jobs.id as campaign_job_id', 'campaign_jobs.start_time as local_start_time',
                'campaign_jobs.start_time as local_start_time', 'campaign_jobs.start_time as local_start_time', 'campaign_jobs.start_time as local_start_time',
                DB::raw("(select companies.name from companies join brands on brands.company_id = companies.id where brands.id =$campaign->brand_id) as company"),
                DB::raw("(select count(id) from campaign_results where direction = 'outbound-api' and reCall = '0' and campaign_job_id =$campaign_job->id ) as total_outbound"),
                DB::raw("(select count(id) as aggregate from campaign_results where  com_platform_status = 'completed' and direction = 'outbound-api' and campaign_job_id = $campaign_job->id ) as total_answered")
            )
            ->whereCampaignId(35)
            ->get();


        $campaign_jobs_summary = $campaign_jobs_summary->push($campaign_job_totals);
    }

    return $campaign_jobs_summary;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line of code to

```
DB::raw("(select count(id) from campaign_results where direction = 'outbound-api' and reCall = '0' and campaign_job_id =".$campaign_job->id." ) as total_outbound");
```

Comment: that did not change the output

Answer (score 0):

ok the issue was returning the query as get() and not first() inside the loop and changing whereCampaignId to whereId by campaign_jobs.id